# Android MotionEvent - Cant find Left and Right Motion Event

Tags: android

i am developing one application in which there is an imageview...in which i want to move left or right using mouse touch...

for that i found "android.view.MotionEvent" but in MotionEvent there are few events among that

1. ACTION_CANCEL     2. ACTION_DOWN  3. ACTION_UP ......etc.

hence there is no such event for "LEFT" and "RIGHT" action....

so is there any other way to implement the "LEFT" and "RIGHT" move ??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You misunderstood `MotionEvent` class events.  ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_UP  are equal to pressed and unpressed events.

In order to detect events like LEFT and RIGHT swipe, you have to use Gesture Recognition. Try to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection/938657#938657) example.

Comment: ohhhh....thanx a lot for letting me know "Correct" thing and providing example...

it helps me a lot in my current application....thanx once again