# Android Gesture to that's used on the start screen

Tags: android

What Android Api is used to get the scrolling to the left or to the right on the start screen on Android?

Comment: Perhaps your bounty would be met if you explained what it is you're trying to accomplish. By "start screen", I assume you mean the Launcher, the source of which is freely available. If that doesn't provide the answer you are looking for, consider explaining what it is you ARE looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is by detecting a "Fling" gesture.  The android API has a built in detector for basic gestures like flinging, scrolling, long press, double tap, pinch zoom, etc.

The documentation is available at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html.

What you do is create an instance of GestureDetector, override the onTouchEvent method of the view you are interested in detecting gestures for, and pass the MotionEvent to the GestureDetector.

You also have to supply a OnGestureListener implementation (easiest to extend SimpleOnGestureListener) to the GestureDetector and that will handle all of your gesture events.

Example:

```
class MyView extends View
{
    GestureDetector mGestureDetect;

    public MyView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        mGestureDetect = new GestureDetector(new SimpleOnGestureListener()
        {

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) 
        {
        //check if the fling was in the direction you were interested in
        if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > 0)
        {
        //Do something here
        }
        //fast enough?
        if(velocityX > 50)
        {
        //etc etc
        }

        return true;
        }
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
    {
        mGestureDetector.onTocuhEvent(ev);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's all in the source repository for you to browse:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher/+/master/src/com/android/launcher/Workspace.java

In the later versions it's using [ViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) and [View.onTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) to catch the drag, and doing the calculation manually based on the amount of movement from when the touch started.

The actual movement is just done via [View.scrollBy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#scrollBy(int,%20int)).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [GestureLibraries](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureLibraries.html) class. Read more about it [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/gestures-on-android-16.html).

I haven't used this myself so I can't give you more info, but these might also be useful:

[Android MotionEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155179/android-motionevent-cant-find-left-and-right-motion-event)

[Android - Basic Gesture Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection)

Comment: That means I have to basically create the gesture on my own and there isn't a fixed gesture for going left or right already in place?

The gesture even works on the start screen of my phone with Android 1.5 while the class that you linked to is introduced in Android 1.6.

Comment: @Christian you don't have to build a complex gesture for a simple thing like a fling.  There are built in convienience classes for common casses like that.