# Android launcher home screen

Tags: android, android-launcher

In the android home screen, we have the ability to slide the screen left and right and display multiple pages. Each of these pages has a different set of icons. In the Mac world these would be called "spaces". What are they called in the Android world?

More importantly is there a standard control that can be used to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such control to achieve this. Once I was digging through the Launcher's source code and this effect is done by creating few LinearLayouts and placing them side by side in the code. Sliding through the "spaces" is done by handlig touch events. Also the grid that handles widgets is created using aviable API.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a standard control for that sliding effect.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188242/android-gesture-to-thats-used-on-the-start-screen) is another question about the effect which also contains a few pointers about implementing it.